# How can I parse JSON arrays with C++ Boost?

Tags: c++, json, boost, boost-propertytree

I have a file containing some JSON content that looks like:

```
{
  "frame":
  {
    "id": "0",
    "points":
    [
      [ "0.883", "0.553", "0" ],
      [ "0.441", "0.889", "0" ],
    ]
  },
  "frame":
  ...
}
```

How do I parse the values of the double array using C++ and Boost ptree?

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/property_tree/reference.html#header.boost.property_tree.json_parser_hpp

Comment: PTree will accept it, but strictly speaking repeated property names are not valid JSON.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use the iterators, Luke.

First , you have to parse the file:

```
boost::property_tree::ptree doc;
boost::property_tree::read_json("input_file.json", doc);
```

... now, because it seems you have multiple "frame" keys in the top level dictionary you must iterate over them:

```
BOOST_FOREACH (boost::property_tree::ptree::value_type& framePair, doc) {
    // Now framePair.first == "frame" and framePair.second is the subtree frame dictionary
}
```

Iterating over the rows and columns is the same:

```
BOOST_FOREACH (boost::property_tree::ptree::value_type& rowPair, frame.get_child("points")) {
    // rowPair.first == ""
    BOOST_FOREACH (boost::property_tree::ptree::value_type& itemPair, rowPair.second) {
        cout << itemPair.second.get_value<std::string>() << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

I didn't test the code, but the idea will work :-)

Comment: `get_value` is a function, so you need `()`. Haven't set up boost but it looks legit otherwise.

Comment: worked for me with framePair.second.get_child("points") as you said and i had to change the data type in the cout from double to string. thank you for helping!!

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the problems you mentioned.