# Retrieve content from JSON in C++ using Boost library

Tags: c++, json, boost

This is my JSON file.

```
{
    "found":3,
    "totalNumPages":1,
    "pageNum":1,
    "results":
    [
        {
            "POSTAL":"000000"
        },
        {
            "POSTAL":"111111"
        },
        {
            "POSTAL":"222222"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is the C++ code.

```
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    // Short alias for this namespace
    namespace pt = boost::property_tree;

    // Create a root
    pt::ptree root;

    // Load the json file in this ptree
    pt::read_json("filename.json", root);

    std::vector< std::pair<std::string, std::string> > results; 
    // Iterator over all results
    for (pt::ptree::value_type &result : root.get_child("results"))
    {
        // Get the label of the node
        std::string label = result.first;
        // Get the content of the node
        std::string content = result.second.data();
        results.push_back(std::make_pair(label, content));
        cout << result.second.data();
    }
}
```

I need to get each set of child value reside in the parent (`"results"`) but it prints out blank. I have tried using

```
root.get_child("results.POSTAL")
```

but because of the square bracket, it will throw error. Any advice?

Comment: this should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17124652/how-can-i-parse-json-arrays-with-c-boost

Comment: Please get into the habit of copying the exact error message into the question.

Answer (score 3):

Arrays in Boost Property Tree are represented as objects with multiple unnamed properties.

Therefore, just loop over them:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/877dee6d711fdd27)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    namespace pt = boost::property_tree;
    pt::ptree root;
    pt::read_json("filename.json", root);

    std::vector< std::pair<std::string, std::string> > results; 
    // Iterator over all results
    for (pt::ptree::value_type &result : root.get_child("results."))
        for (pt::ptree::value_type &field : result.second)
            results.push_back(std::make_pair(field.first, field.second.data()));

    for (auto& p : results)
        std::cout << p.first << ": " << p.second << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
POSTAL: 000000
POSTAL: 111111
POSTAL: 222222
```